# Ubuntu 20.10 4K Resolution Issues

Tags: hdmi, display-resolution, 20.10, 4k-monitor

I connected my Laptop with a HDMI 2.1 cable to my 4K TV. But unfortunately the TV output resolution is till 1080p. Please advice on how to get it to work. Even the display setting only shows a max of 1920x1080 resolution. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us about the graphics chip/card of your laptop (brand name and model) or if built-in (as part of the CPU), the brand name and model of the CPU. - Also, check that you are not sending the same graphical data (image) to the laptop's built-in screen and the TV, but that you are sending a separate image to the TV. - See more details via the internet, for example at [this link](https://www.techhive.com/article/3330376/do-i-need-a-4k-hdmi-cable.html).

Comment: Also go through your TV settings and disable any post-processing options. These don't work well when using a TV as a display for a computer.